# Skeleton tracking using openni_tracker

Tags: openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use openni_tracker to track skeletons. After running the command **rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker** . the Kinect is able to detect new users but nothing happens after that.

Please can anyone tell me how Im suppose to track skeletons with it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252494/skeleton-tracking-using-openni_tracker/) by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The **openni_tracker** node publishes new users as frames. The node generates a frame for each limb (hand, arm, head, leg, and so on) of the detected person. You can check the result with RVIZ by setting the gui to visualize data about tf and by setting as fixed frame the Kinect's frame.

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on 2017-01-20**:
To visualize this on Rviz do I just run Rviz normally using the command **rosrun rviz rviz**  ? @Chaos

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2017-01-23**:
You need also to configure RVIZ to visualize frames. Press the **add** button on the bottom left, search for "**tf**" and add it. Make sure you set the right fixed frame.